# C# UWP How to subscribe to UPnP Event

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, upnp

I hope you can help me. Right know I'm trying to develop a nice little MediaController app for Windows-10 UWP (For my Lumia950 and my PC).

For the moment I can send SOAP-Messages to retrieve informations of my existing MediaRenderer or MediaServer

```
=> Code snipped
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(control_url));
request.Headers.Add("SOAPACTION", "\""+ service_type + "#" + this.Name + "\"");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
HttpStringContent requestContent = new HttpStringContent(xml.ToString(), Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "text/xml");
request.Content = requestContent;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
```

But I'm totally lost how to subscribe to the upnp events. I searched the web for hours but couldn't find some guidance. As far as I understood I need to create a HttpRequest with "SUBSCRIBE" as method?! I need to give tom ipaddress for callback as well (how to figure out which port is free? and how to get noticed if the upnpdevice fired an event?). But that's it.

Any help and code samples would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read [Universal Plug and Play Device Architecture](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v2.0.pdf) chapter 4 ("Eventing")?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes I read this already. But I can't figure out how to do it in C# for UWP?! Thanks for your help